# How can i do a Booking function in SpringBoot/Angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I'm a newbie in SpringBoot/Angular4 and I'm stuck on a function for days now and I hope you people can help me.

So here is the thing:
I have an entity `Reservation` **(Booking in English)** and an entity `Voyage` **(Travel in English)** where the `Reservation` class have a foreign key (`Voyage_id`). So I want to book a travel **(OneToMany mapping)** but I'm confuse on how to do it.

Here is my controller for `Reservation` in SpringBoot

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postReservation/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Reservation> createReservation(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody Reservation newReservation) {
        Reservation reservData = reservationRepository.findOneVoyageBy(id);
        reservData.setVoyage_id(newReservation.getVoyage_id());

        Reservation reservDone = reservationRepository.save(reservData);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(reservDone, HttpStatus.OK);

        //return new ResponseEntity<Reservation>(reservationservices.save(newReservation), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

My service Class in Angular 4:

```
@Injectable()
export class ReservationService {
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  createReservation(id: number, value: any):Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post(AppComponent.API_URL + '/reservation/postReservation' + id, value)
      .map(resp => resp.json());
  }
```

My Component.ts function:

```
save(reserv){
    this.reservationService.createReservation(reserv.id,
    {
      voyage: reserv.voyage
    }).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      reserv = data as Reservation;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

In order to explain clearly what I want, you will see in the Output below a list of available **Voyages(Travels)**. When I click on the button that I have circle in red, I want to persist in the `Reservation` class the `id` of the travel I have clicked on.

[image]

So here is my problem. Hoping I have made myself clear, I hope you guys can help me.

EDIT: With all above, when i click on the button it tells me something like

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

What I understood on this is that it cant't retrieve the `id` of the Travel I clicked on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it's me but, you described a part of your current situation but you didn't really say what was not working... 
Also, but it's a detail, if you identify your resource, you should use a PUT instead of a POST. But that's outside of the scope of your question.

Comment: @M3enjamin sorry for that i just forgot... i have edited the post so you can see what's wrong. Thanks

Comment: It looks like it cannot read the property 'id' of 'reserv' on the client side.
Are you sure you actually pass it a value? here ==> save(reserv)

Comment: @M3enjamin i passed the value ==>save(a) and now it tells me something like: **java.util.NoSuchElementException","message":"No message available","path":"/reservation/postReservation/1"}**

Comment: Honestly it's hard tu help you with the small bits of code you provided.
My guess would be that spring data jpa throws you that exception but I'm not really sure. You should try calling your service directly (via a tool like soapui or postman for example) with mock data to verify it's actually working.

Comment: @M3enjamin thanks for trying to help me...indeed i have used Postman and it still the same error message... sorry for that but what additionnal code can i send if you don't mind